# Have they re-cast any of the X-men actor within a particular "timeline" series?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe

I've not watched most of the X-Men films after the first couple, but clearly they've been making them long enough that they've needed to re-cast people.  As far as I know, that was done by shifting to the "First Class" series/timeline, with younger versions of the characters. So there's two different people playing Xavier, Cyclops, etc. (and yet still only one Wolverine...)

But I can't recall if they ever needed to re-cast any characters within any/either of those timeline/series of films.  I suspect Beast was recast in the original run, cause I don't think Kelsey Grammer did more than one film, but I could very well be mistaken.

They've done so in the main Marvel films (Rhodey being the obvious example) but I'm not sure of any in the X-Men films. Anyone?

Comment: With Disney buying Fox, that means they can bring X-Men into the MCU. Presumably *Logan* ended the XCU ([Hugh Jackman has hinted at that](https://www.polygon.com/2017/12/12/16766394/disney-fox-deal-marvel-xmen-fantastic-four-avengers-deadpool)). As such, they would likely recast everyone

Answer (score 1):

### William Stryker

**Brian Cox** played William Stryker in the 2003 film, X2: X-Men United.

[image: Brian Cox]

Set in the same universe (albeit intended to be a younger version of the character), **Danny Huston** takes over the role for X-Men Origins: Wolverine.

[image: Danny Huston]

### Colossus

In X2: X-Men United, X-Men: The Last Stand, and X-Men: Days of Future Past, **Daniel Cudmore** plays Colossus.

[image: Daniel Cudmore]

In Deadpool and Deadpool 2, Colossus is mostly CGI and voiced by Stefan Kapicic

[image: Stefan Kapicic]

In the original 2003 X-Men film, he has an uncredited cameo as a student drawing. I can't seem to find an image or the actor, though.

### Hank McCoy/Beast

**Steve Bacic** played made a brief appearance as Hank McCoy in X2: X-Men United.

[image: Steve Bacic]

**Kelsey Grammer** plays the role in X-Men: The Last Stand

[image: Kelsey Grammer]

There are several others but this should be sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: How can you forgot Kitty Pryde

Comment: Except for Beast, I don't think the other examples really depict recastings made withing the same series/timeline, as the OP asked for.